# Node-steam-trade, how to get items names?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm making a steamBot, that take items from users and I need to get the name of this items and it's price to send it on my site.
How I should get the name of each item in items array?
I have alreay know items[i].appid assetid and others, but how can I get the name and average price?

```
 steam.on('tradeOffers', function(number) {
  if (number > 0) {
    offers.getOffers({
      get_received_offers: 1,
      active_only: 1,
      time_historical_cutoff: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)
    }, function(error, body) {
      if(body.response.trade_offers_received) {
        body.response.trade_offers_received.forEach(function(offer) {
          if (offer.trade_offer_state == 2) {
            console.log(offer);
            console.log('Recieved trade offer: ' + offer.tradeofferid);

            var exception = false;
            var items = offer.items_to_receive;
            for(var i=0; i< items.length;i++)
            {
                if(items[i].appid != "730")
                {
                    exception = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var descriptionOfItems = ""; // assetid + classid
            for(var i=0; i< items.length;i++)
            {
                appid += items[i].assetid + "-" + items[i].classid + " ";
            }


            if (!offer.items_to_give && !exception) {
              offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});
              console.log("Offer accepted");
              steam.sendMessage(offer.steamid_other, "Thanks you!");
              if (offer.steamid_other !== admin) {
                steam.sendMessage(admin, offer.steamid_other+ " - " + descriptionOfItems + " just donated!");
              }
            } else {
              offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});
              console.log("Don't receive items from other's games!");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm I'm still looking for a better way to do this, but in the mean time, you can do this:

Included in the trade offer object is the "steamid_other" you can use it to query their inventory:

```
'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + steamid_other + '/inventory/json/730/2/?l=english'
```

you can then match the items in the trade to the ones in their inventory and access the "market_hash_name" which can be used to query price information, like so:

```
'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=' + encodeURI(items[key].market_hash_name)
```

Let me know if you find a better solution, good luck